# Приоритет отображения элементов

Tags: bootstrap

Нужно сделать элемент как показано на картинке

[image]

Все бы ничего, только когда начинаю двигать верхнюю кнопку на место, она залазит под слой Well'a а не на него, вот так

[image]

подскажите каким образом можно задать приоритет кнопке/слою/еще чему-нибудь
чтобы она надвигалась НА Well, а не под него.
Вот код элемента

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-2">
           <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Старт</div>
           <div class="well">
             <div class="table-responsive" align="center">
                          <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center">
                                Что это такое?
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center">
                                Что это такое?
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center">
                                Что это такое?
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center">
                                Что это такое?
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                </div><!--EO Table--->
              </div><!--EO Well--->
           <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Купить сейчас</div>
         </div> <!--EO Co1--->
       </div><!--EO Row--->
    </div><!--EO Container--->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Кнопки я двигаю в bootstrap.css, с помощью псевдокласса .nth-child()

```
.btn-primary:nth-child(1){
margin-bottom: -20px;
margin-left:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

добавьте

```
.btn-primary:nth-child(1){
   margin-bottom: -20px;
   margin-left:9px;
   z-index: 1;
   position: relative;
}
```

Пример

```css
.btn-primary:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    margin-left:9px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Старт</div>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="table-responsive" align="center">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">Что это такое?</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">Что это такое?</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">Что это такое?</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">Что это такое?</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--EO Table--->
            </div>
            <!--EO Well--->
            <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Купить сейчас</div>
        </div>
        <!--EO Co1--->
    </div>
    <!--EO Row--->
</div>
<!--EO Container--->
```